# Ext js Spinner field issue

Tags: extjs

I getting an issue in [Ext.form.field.Spinner](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Spinner) field in extjs

when I am adding it in my form its looking like this.

[image]

[image]

Below is the code that I have added in my application.

```
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomSpinner', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Spinner',
    alias: 'widget.customspinner',
    //override onSpinUp (using step isn't neccessary)
    xLabel: '',
    onSpinUp: function () {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.readOnly) {
            var val = parseInt(me.getValue().split(' '), 10) || 0; // gets rid of " Pack", defaults to zero on parse failure
            me.setValue((val + me.step) + ' ' + me.xLabel);
        }
    },
    // override onSpinDown
    onSpinDown: function () {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.readOnly) {
            var val = parseInt(me.getValue().split(' '), 10) || 0; // gets rid of " Pack", defaults to zero on parse failure
            if (val <= me.step) {
                me.setValue('Default');
            } else {
                me.setValue((val - me.step) + ' ' + me.xLabel);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In form, I have added the custom spinner

```
{
   xtype: 'customspinner',
   fieldLabel: 'No Data',
   xLabel: 'Min.',
   step: 30
},
```

I dont know why this desing issue is comming. I used code that sencha doc described [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Spinner)

Any solution?

Comment: Can you share a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) please ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on many versions (ex. 4.2.0.663, 4.2.1.883, 5.0.1.1255, 6.7.0...) of extjs and described problem doesn't exists

Take a look on fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2t3g

You need to attach full code - where the `customspinner` is used

Comment: I added some CSS for that component and adjusted it as I want. Thank you.